# Facebook API - create post draft for a page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I have a Python code that calls Facebook API to publish a post on my page. The code works well to publish a post or to create a draft and then publish it. For example this is a code to create a draft and then publish it based on its `id`.

```
facebook_access_token = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_ACCESS_TOKEN')
page_id = os.getenv('FACEBOOK_PAGE_ID')
message = 'This is a test post from FB SDK'

graph = facebook.GraphAPI(access_token=facebook_access_token, version='3.1')

draft_post = graph.put_object(parent_object=page_id, connection_name='feed', message=message, published=False)

page_post_id = draft_post['id']

publish_post = graph.request(f"{page_post_id}", post_args={'is_published': 'true'})
```

The thing is that I would like to create a draft and **not** publish it. I want to be able to see it on Facebook website and then decide whether to publish or not.

The problem is that the draft created this way is nowhere to be found. It is nowhere on the page. Internet says it should be found in the Meta Business Suite, but it is not there either.

[image: Meta business suite draft view]

I know my permissions are right since it allows me to create and then publish the draft.
What is the problem here?